# finding foreign keys in ms sql server with information_schema

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, information-schema

I'm trying to find all the tables that have foreign keys pointing to a particular table. So I wrote this:

```
select t1.TABLE_NAME as pointsfrom, t2.TABLE_NAME as pointsto
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS r
        join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS t1 on t1.CONSTRAINT_NAME=r.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS t2 on t2.CONSTRAINT_NAME=r.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
        where t2.table_name = @mytable
```

This works 90% of the time, or to be exact, for 22 of the 24 foreign keys in the database I'm working on. But for 2 FKs, the unique_constraint_name does not match any name in table_constraints.

The names are also a little funny. One of them is "environment designator", with a space. The field the FK points to is named "environment_designator", with an underscore. The other has a unique_constraint_name of "filename is unique", which doesn't correspond to anything I see in the definition of either the "from" or the "to" table.

Is there some place else I should look for a match on unique_constraint_name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id), OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id)
    FROM sys.foreign_keys
    WHERE referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@mytable)
```

Comment: Well, this does indeed appear to work. I was hoping for a solution using information_schema because, (a) i'm already using information_schema elsewhere in this app and I'd like to be consistent; and (b) I've never used the sys catalog tables and I just didn't want to get into it. But something that works is always preferable to something that doesn't work, so I think I'll take your solution. If someone else comes along and knows a way to make it work with information_schema, please post! I doubt I'll switch back if the sys cat solution works, but enquiring minds want to know.

Comment: @Jay See [The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views) for some additional information.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm figuring that out. Well I doubt I'll redo existing working code, I think next time around I'll just go with the SQL Server - specific objects. I had this silly idea that it was better to use information_schema because that's supposed to be an industry standard.